# Trying to make a UIButton a circle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uibutton

Im currently trying to make a button into a circle shape and here is my code:

```
  var raffleButton:UIButton = {
    var button = UIButton()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 19)
    button.setTitle("Tap To Enter Raffle!", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .white
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true

    button.frame = CGRect(x: 1600, y: 160, width: 160, height: 160)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.width/2

    return button
}()
```

However when I run the code the button is disfigured and looks like the following... round and football like.
[image]

Is there any reason why the button looks like it does instead of being a circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some confusion as to whether you are using autolayout or not.

You have set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`, but then you are trying to manipulate the frame.

If you add constraints to set the width & height, you will get a result closer to what you are after, but you will still need to adjust your label or font to get it to fit:

```
var raffleButton:UIButton = {
    var button = UIButton()
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 19)
    button.setTitle("Tap To Enter Raffle!!", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .white
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true

    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160).isActive = true
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160).isActive = true
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 80

    return button
}()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you set `button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`, this code won't work `button.frame = CGRect(x: 1600, y: 160, width: 160, height: 160)`. The button's size will be changed during the layout process(won't be (160, 160) anymore). Therefore, it's not a circle.

you can either change `button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` or try setting button's `cornerRadius` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.

Answer (score 1):

your button Height same as button width and then set this code..

```
anyButton.backgroundColor = .clear

anyButton.layer.cornerRadius = anyButton.frame.height / 2

anyButton.layer.borderWidth = 1

anyButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

Answer (score 0):

One semi-obvious thing to note, is if the button frame's height and width is not equal, it will not be a circle :).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).